# Is this .sh file malicious? I don't know where it came from

Tags: bash

I was just browsing my server and found a suspicious file in one of the directories. It's a .sh file, and after researching it, I understand that it's the Linux equivalent of a Windows batch file.

That's good to learn...but I didn't put it there. And I have only located one instance of it, here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#(filename).jpg

for file in $(find . -name '*_?_*.jpg' -print)
do
newfile=$(echo $file | sed 's/_\(.\)_/_0\1_/')
mv $file $newfile
done
```

The `(filename)` is my replacement for the filename in this script.

What I want to know, in order to learn from this, is if this was a malicious file and what it looks like it's purpose may have been?

Again, I did not place this file there, I don't routinely access my server through SSH, so this raised some concern. Any help would be genuinely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't seem malefic, it just renames jpg files using a regular expression.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is that really necessary? I know nothing of what this file was about which is why I posted the question here. Now I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script just renames .jpg files which have a name like:

```
Nice_Picture_2_.jpg
```

to

```
Nice_Picture_02_.jpg
```

no malware

Comment: Nice_Picture_2_.jpg, not Nice_Picture_(2)_.jpg. The escaped parenthesis is just sed for memoization.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. This time I've tested it ;)

Comment: Memoization? Capturing, you mean

Comment: Many thanks! Still a complete mystery as to how it got there, but I appreciate the clarity.

Comment: what is the location of the file?

Comment: @hek2mgl The path was something like this content/year/month/file.sh In the /month/ folder there were photos in separate folders for each month of the year.

Comment: Hmmm. Cannot say why the file is stored there. But it is harmless.

Comment: @hek2mgl Well, at least I learned what it was, many thanks again!